# Assign value to dynamically created scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a means to toggle dynamically created rows of information. I've tried using ng-init, and then passing it to a function, but I'm screwing up somewhere and I can't seem to wrap my head around how or if this is possible. The gap, I believe, is in getting the concatenated scope variable to be referenced elsewhere. I'm using Bootstrap 3 and AngularJS 1.5.

The HTML:

```
<div class="row" data-ng-repeat="equipment in task.equipment">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h4 class="green-text">
      {{ equipment.equipId }}
      <small class="green-text">
        <i class="glyphicon" 
          data-ng-class="{'glyphicon-triangle-bottom': field{{ $index }}, 'glyphicon-triangle-right': !field{{ $index }}}" 
          data-ng-init="equipment['field' + $index] = true" 
          data-ng-click="toggleTaskEquip('field{{ $index }}')">
        field{{ $index }}: I WANT THIS TO WORK</i>
      </small>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div data-ng-show="field{{ $index }}">
          ...stuff here...
  </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
$scope.toggleTaskEquip = function(toggleBool)
  {
    if (toggleBool === true)
      $scope.isTaskEquipOpen = false;
    else if (toggleBool === false)
      $scope.isTaskEquipOpen = true;
  };
```

Comment: Could you provide us an example on plukker or put some more codes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to be able to toggle the `boolean` created in the `ng-init` with a click.

I think you need this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="equipment in task.equipment">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4 class="green-text">
          {{equipment.equipId}}
          <small class="green-text">
            <i class="glyphicon" 
               data-ng-class="{'glyphicon-triangle-bottom': isVisible, 'glyphicon-triangle-right': !isVisible}"
               data-ng-init="isVisible = true" 
               data-ng-click="isVisible = !isVisible">I WANT THIS TO WORK</i>
          </small>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div data-ng-show="isVisible">
        ...stuff here...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You don't even need the function `toggleTaskEquip` on the `$scope`.

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dx52sxLm/2/).

`ng-repeat` creates a [new scope for each template instance](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), so you can just create a separate `isVisible` for each `equipment` with `isVisible = true` in the `ng-init`.

Comment: Thank you! Talk about trying to over-complicate a process.